# AddEventListener dynamic function reference to anonymous function

Tags: javascript, function, dynamic, reference, addeventlistener

So I have a function and I want to be able to create and remove the function with a reference to an anonymous function.  I want to do this to provide the ability to create the same function for multiple object.  Currently when I create one function and then create another I believe it is overwriting the reference with the newest one and that does not allow me to remove the older reference.

So I want to dynamically create the reference with a variable with something like this.

```
image.addEventListener("click", 
    (Highlight + image.alt) = function (){ HighLightClick(this) }, false);
```

and then remove it like this

```
TileClicked.removeEventListener("click", (Highlight + TileClicked.alt), false);
```

Do I have to create a variable for TileClicked or how would one go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
var functionMap = {};

funtionMap[Highlight + image.alt] = function (){ HighLightClick(this) };
image.addEventListener("click", funtionMap[Highlight + image.alt], false);

TileClicked.removeEventListener("click", funcionMap[Highlight + TileClicked.alt], false);
```

Comment: Does not seem to work I know you need something like this to work 

image.addEventListener("click",FunctionMap = funtionMap[Highlight + image.alt], false);

Having that equal sign allows me to call the reference to allow me to delete it.  Its just knowing how to dynamically create and set is the problem.

Comment: The second line in the code above sets the function (dynamically creates it and saves it) as a property of the `functionMap` object, which is what you can use to 'name' it (i.e., you shouldn't need another name and equals sign).

Comment: Yea however the addEventListener is very weird in the fact that it takes in the function differently for instance image.addEventListener("click", funtionMap, false); will work but when you use something like: image.addEventListener("click", funtionMap(this), false); it will not work properly thus why I use an anon function.  Think the same thing is happening with your way of doing it.

Comment: Yes, `this` probably isn't right the way I've done it. You might try just using 'image' instead.